# Sort numbers by matching date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the desired output but i am not getting the formula for it.
I tried this formula `=WENN(S9=$E$5;"0";WENN(R10=0;S10+1;WENN(T10=0;S10-1;U10+1)))`
Principle is when the data match it should show "0" below it and others should get sorted accordingly.
EG: DATE= FEB 21(E5) when this date is matched to Months rows the output in Output Row should be like the shown below(Required Output).
Please Check the image for more clarification:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DATEDIF function:

```
=IFERROR(DATEDIF($A$1;A2;"m");DATEDIF(A2;$A$1;"m")*-1)
```

[image]